# Certain Li elements show as white space, but link is there after adding new CSS

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/alex1236/f224nx8o/1/ I'm having an issue, since I added my CSS at the bottom for my navbar. The new issue is that under the column status and NAS there is no text, but there is a link. I haven't touched the text or link to them yet, so I am very confused as to why this is happening. It seems to only happen when I input my special dot.tk URL. I have 2 instances of the same URL used twice and one of each is blank.
Some code:

```css
.Online {
    color:#16a085;
}
.checking, .unchecked {
    color:#FF8C00;
}
.Offline {
    color:red;
}
li {
    text-decoration: none
}
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff5cb85c', filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff337ab7', endColorstr='#ff2b669a', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-color:#2b669a
}
.list-group-item.active .badge, .list-group-item.active:focus .badge, .list-group-item.active:hover .badge {
    text-shadow:none
}
.panel {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
}
.panel-default>.panel-heading {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f5f5f5), to(#e8e8e8));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5 0, #e8e8e8 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff5f5f5', endColorstr='#ffe8e8e8', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.panel-primary>.panel-heading {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 0, #2e6da4 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 0, #2e6da4 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#337ab7), to(#2e6da4));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #337ab7 0, #2e6da4 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff337ab7', endColorstr='#ff2e6da4', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.panel-success>.panel-heading {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dff0d8 0, #d0e9c6 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #dff0d8 0, #d0e9c6 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dff0d8), to(#d0e9c6));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #dff0d8 0, #d0e9c6 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffdff0d8', endColorstr='#ffd0e9c6', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.panel-info>.panel-heading {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9edf7 0, #c4e3f3 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #d9edf7 0, #c4e3f3 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d9edf7), to(#c4e3f3));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9edf7 0, #c4e3f3 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffd9edf7', endColorstr='#ffc4e3f3', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.panel-warning>.panel-heading {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcf8e3 0, #faf2cc 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fcf8e3 0, #faf2cc 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fcf8e3), to(#faf2cc));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcf8e3 0, #faf2cc 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffcf8e3', endColorstr='#fffaf2cc', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.panel-danger>.panel-heading {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2dede 0, #ebcccc 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f2dede 0, #ebcccc 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2dede), to(#ebcccc));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2dede 0, #ebcccc 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff2dede', endColorstr='#ffebcccc', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.well {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e8e8e8 0, #f5f5f5 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e8e8e8 0, #f5f5f5 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e8e8e8), to(#f5f5f5));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #e8e8e8 0, #f5f5f5 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffe8e8e8', endColorstr='#fff5f5f5', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-color:#dcdcdc;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)
}
#nav {
 display:block;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin:auto;
 padding:auto;
 text-align:center;
 width:300px;
 text-decoration:none; 
 font-family:sans-serif;
}
#works {
 margin: auto;
    width: 96%;
 position:absolute;
 top:125px;
}
ul#nav
    {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
 position: fixed;
    top: 7px;
    }
    li#navitem
    {
    display:inline;
    }
    li#navitem a:link,a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #27AE60;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}    
li#navitem a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #2980B9;
}
#navbar{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:#34495e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <html>
        
        <head>
            <title>Dashboard</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme-min.css">
            <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="navbar"></div>
            <ul id="nav">
                    <li id="navitem"><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="navitem"><a href="/works.html">Work</a></li>
                    <li id="navitem"><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li id="navitem"><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="container">                
                <h1 style="color:#16a085"> Server Status Webpage</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h3 class="panel-title">Important Info</h3>

                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WE10MO1HmnmiMJNORdOr5TliBvMaU8WoYqfZbHCil3c/edit?usp=sharing" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i> Home Network Protocol</a> - Home Network IPs and Passwords</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h3 class="panel-title">NAS</h3>

                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="http://g.tk" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></i> FreeNAS</a> - NAS control</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://g.tk" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></i> OwnCloud</a> - Access Files Anywhere</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h3 class="panel-title"> Main Network</h3>

                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="http://10.0.0.1" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> Xfinity</a> - Modem</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="http://192.168.0.1" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></i> D-Link Access Point</a> - Router Settings and Controls</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h3 class="panel-title">Status</h3>

                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                                        //<![CDATA[
                                        window.onload = function() {
                                            function ping(ip, callback) {

                                                if (!this.inUse) {
                                                    this.status = 'unchecked';
                                                    this.inUse = true;
                                                    this.callback = callback;
                                                    this.ip = ip;
                                                    var _that = this;
                                                    this.img = new Image();
                                                    this.img.onload = function() {
                                                        _that.inUse = false;
                                                        _that.callback('responded');

                                                    };
                                                    this.img.onerror = function(e) {
                                                        if (_that.inUse) {
                                                            _that.inUse = false;
                                                            _that.callback('- Online', e);
                                                        }

                                                    };
                                                    this.start = new Date().getTime();
                                                    this.img.src = "http://" + ip;
                                                    this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                                                        if (_that.inUse) {
                                                            _that.inUse = false;
                                                            _that.callback('- Offline');
                                                        }
                                                    }, 1500);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            var PingModel = function(servers) {
                                                var self = this;
                                                var myServers = [];
                                                ko.utils.arrayForEach(servers, function(location) {
                                                    myServers.push({
                                                        name: location,
                                                        status: ko.observable('unchecked')
                                                    });
                                                });
                                                self.servers = ko.observableArray(myServers);
                                                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.servers(), function(s) {
                                                    s.status('checking');
                                                    new ping(s.name, function(status, e) {
                                                        s.status(status);
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            };
                                            var komodel = new PingModel([
                                                'g.tk:443',
                                                'g.tk',
                                                'g.tk:9091', ]);
                                            ko.applyBindings(komodel);
                                        } //]]>
                                    </script>
                                    <ul data-bind="foreach:servers">
                                        <li> <a href="#" data-bind="text:name,attr:{href: 'http://'+name}">tester</a>  <span data-bind="text:status,css:status"></span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h3 class="panel-title">HP DL380 G5</h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">2x Quad Core Xeon X5450s, 24GB RAM, iLO2 - FreeNAS 9.2.15</div>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="http://192.168.0.102" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-console"></i> iLO2</a> - Server Health and Status Management Suite</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://g.tk" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></i> OwnCloud</a> - Access Files Anywhere</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="http://g.tk:9091" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i> Transmission</a> - BitTorrent Downloader Web Interface</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h3 class="panel-title">HP DL360 G5</h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">2x Dual Core Xeon 5130s, 16GB RAM, iLO2 - Windows 8.1</div>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="http://192.168.0.112" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-console"></i> iLO2</a> - Server Health and Status Management Suite</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="http://g.tk:3389" target="_new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i> Remote Desktop</a> - Access a Computer From Anywhere</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue. Could you simplify your code snippet to only show the area where the issue is found?

Comment: @RicardoRossi check the JSFiddle link, the code snippet thing is bad for some reason and doesn't show the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following css syles to your code that will solve your problem , add another class `.dff` to your `<ul class="list-group">` like this `<ul class="list-group diff">` above `<li class="list-group-item">` and `script` in status div.

```
.diff{
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}

.list-group-item > a{
    color:blue;
}

.list-group-item > ul >li > a{
    color:blue;
}
```

this will solve your problem specific to NAS and also status.

Comment: It's now also affecting just about every Li element with white space. At least 1 link in every one of my boxes is white space now. I'll try adding this code to see if it gets fixed. But then the problem with adding this is that it will not have the list-group code it needs from my Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: It's now also affecting just about every Li element with white space. At least 1 link in every one of my boxes is white space now. I'll try adding this code to see if it gets fixed. But then the problem with adding this is that it will not have the list-group code it needs from my Bootstrap CSS. Disregard that, you sir are a saint. Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful!!